# Typescript: Problem with generic Parameter/ReturnType and string Enums

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I currently try to add proper typings to the following simplified function:

```js
getProperty(property:string):any
```

My goal is to make it possible to pass the property parameter as `string` or `string enum` and get the correct return type for it.

For that I have created a new `string enum` Property:

```
enum Property {
    ENABLED = 'enabled',
    SIZE    = 'size'
}
```

a `generic type` PropertyType:

```
type PropertyType < T > =
    T extends Property.ENABLED ? boolean :
    T extends Property.SIZE    ? number  : any;
```

and changed the function signature to:

```
getProperty<T extends Property>(property : T) : PropertyType<T>
```

This works perfect if I call the function with the new `string enum`:

```
const enabled: boolean = getProperty(Property.ENABLED);
```

But if I call the function with a simple string (needed for backward compatibility) like that:

```
const enabled: boolean = getProperty("enabled");
```

I get the following error:

```
Argument of type '"enabled"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Property'.(2345)
```

Is there any good way to support both ways (`string` & `string enum`) to pass the property parameter?

My example is also available here: [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=32&ssc=57&pln=32&pc=1#code/PTCiA8EMFsAcBsCmACAapeBXFBnALgPYBOiAUAMYEB2+y+xiAXMgN7IDaA1ogJ7P5EAllQDmAXWaQqPZAF9kAXlalkq5ACJEVSACMkAE3XM8RbABoVa9TkEAvREeQAWUrIDcpUiAC0vv-4DAoOCQ0LDgzxAAZRNhEWRQKkxoZAAFIgJYRCI8HlItZLSMrJyZFktVUAA5AEEAIQAZUAARRWQAci1dA3aLNWQogEkALVB+pXabe3bXSOBwhcWl5f859Mzs3OQAFR4snFJcrKKN0t3jgB4d5AA+RVJt5ERwPC19HBOS3IA6avqm1oAfmQOgIBCQUmQjAeTxebw+6y+PG+Q1G-WBSWgOmyqkk0g8XnmK2JJJJc2QAHEtNlBORkCJEHhEZsZAAzTBUch4QTUUjsznc6j0xnM0oXR7PV5Ud6fFk3AAUsGKLKhOwAlKrRblzohxTdSOV+iQ8JgiFQ6IQSOwladcmIPLI5qTnS6wp5KDQ8E9tHpEPoAAzMUHgxCQpQMpnK0ryrXIv6NFpqjwe2hTRCB5CY7FENoR2MxqM-VGgJPu6i0Lq+-QARiDYIh5vDIsLPHlmh9BnUpZTXrTtczyWzuebttb1jsDiTQA)

Answer (score 1):

You can either [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) the function or make the type parameter of `getProperty` a union type.

Overload:

```
function getProperty(property: string): any;
function getProperty<T extends Property>(property : T) : PropertyType<T>
{
    return store[property];
}
```

Union Type:

```
function getProperty<T extends Property | string>(property : T) : PropertyType<T>
{
    return store[property];
}
```

Full code:

```
//Example Value store
const store: { [key: string]: any } = {
    "enabled": true,
    "size": 4
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

//String Enum Property
enum Property {
    ENABLED = 'enabled',
    SIZE    = 'size'
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Property Types
type PropertyType < T > =
T extends Property.ENABLED ? boolean :
T extends Property.SIZE    ? number  : any;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Generic getProperty function
 function getProperty<T extends Property | string>(property : T) : PropertyType<T>
    {
        return store[property];
    }

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

const enabled0: boolean = getProperty(Property.ENABLED);
const enabled1: boolean = getProperty('enabled');
```

Another way is to just simply choose a different function name, since you don't gain any type safety from overloading. Imo this is a better option to stay backwards compatible.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was easier than I thought.